# How to check if variable empty on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

How can i make an if else statement in my controller. The problem is that @topvideo shows the latest video of the day but what if no one has uploaded it anything for the day it throws an error. and this feature is on the main page so you cant see the rest of the page because of it.

I want to say if theres `@topvideo.title` empty run this:

```
@topvideo = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").beginning_of_month)
```

else run this:

```
@topvideo = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @videos = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC")
  @items = Video.all.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC")
  @items_by_day = @items.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_day }
  @topvideo = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)    
end
```

**(view)**

```
<div class="novideo">


        <h1>#1</h1>
        <h2>TuChoice<br>
        Today</h2>

        <div class="artisthead"></div>

        <h3><%= @topvideo.first.title %></h3>
        <h4><%= @topvideo.first.artist %></h4>

        <p></p>
    </div>

    <iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @topvideo.first.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: do you want to check `@topvideo.title` empty ? or `@topvideo` empty? Because, if you `@topvideo` is empty that implies that your `@topvideo.title` is also empty. Please clarify and try my answer. That's what that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [blank?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) method which will check for both `nil` and `empty`:

```
if @topvideo.blank?
  @topvideo = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").beginning_of_month)
else
  @topvideo = Video.order("cached_votes_up DESC, created_at DESC").where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
end
```

Comment: Why downvote? I am still editing my code! And, please comment the reason when you downvote!